# Slow write speed on APFS external SSD

Tags: ssd, apfs

The SSD is SanDisk Extreme Pro V2, with original cable, formatted APFS (non-encrypted). OS is 12.0.1. There's 10GB of free space. Write speed used to be close to read speed, about 500MB/s. Now it's about 40MB/s. I don't know if it's related to fragmentation. APFS defragment was disabled by default. Also I don't know whether trim is enabled.

Comment: What's the total capacity of the drive and how old it is?

Comment: What does system information tell us about the actual connection?

Comment: I would edit this to document exactly what cable you use to connect and also how you are running the tests to get the measurements. `diskutil apfs list` might help is see what your settings / connection / layout is as well. Hopefully it’s something you can run a repair or get third party tool to trim the controller and get speed back

Comment: I would try to clear some more space and see if the speed improves. 10Gb is not much.  I don't think fragmentation affects speed on SSDs, does it? There's no 'head' to move about.

Comment: What is the interface of your external SSD, USB or Thunderbolt?

Comment: 10GB free space is not just a bit low, it's ***critical***. You must clear some room 10 - 15% free space] for it to breathe, then TRIM can work properly. SSD drives should never be defragged. Fragmentation is totally irrelevant on an SSD, as data is not stored contiguously.